# How to use cesium with Vuetify (Webpack building error)?

Tags: node.js, webpack, cesiumjs, vuetify.js

I'm a newbie with webpack and I'm trying to use Cesium within Vuetify but I can't get it working because of a dependencies problem:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors 15:16:46

 This dependency was not found:

 * cesium/Source in ./src/main.js

 To install it, you can run: npm install --save cesium/Source
```

I already tried the command `npm install --save cesium/Source` without results.

**Here are the steps I took:**

1. npm install -g vue-cli
2. vue init vuetifyjs/webpack my-project
3. cd my-project
4. npm install
5. npm install --save cesium
6. added the line `import Cesium from 'cesium';` to `./src/main.js`
7. npm run dev #ERROR

Is anyone having an idea ?

Comment: Does your app start without `cesium`? Did you try to install other packages?

Comment: It's working well without the cesium import.
No, I haven't. I don't need other dependencies yet, but I can try a threejs import to check if it's working